# Can't seem to have Flask_login work with gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn, flask-login

I have a flask project that uses flask_login to handle login (duh).
the project architecture is like so :

```
SWAP
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── config.sh
├── get-pip.py
├── requirements.txt
├── run.sh
└── www
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── auth.py
    ├── db.sqlite
    ├── main.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── ressources
    ├── templates
    │   ├── *.html
    ├── tools.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

When i use flask run, everything work as intended, but i tried to use gunicorn and i have

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_manager'
```

Now here is my wsgi.py : https://pastebin.com/CqdKhw0q 
my main.py : https://pastebin.com/HPys576M 
and my auth.py : https://pastebin.com/zLj1ULcC

When i run `gunicorn -w 1 www.wsgi:app`my `/`page works, but if i try to acces `/profile`
which is protected by `@login_required` in my main.py file i run into the error above.

I am new to gunicorn so it might be something stupid.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with gunicorn but with the login_manager that you forgot to configure in flask_login.

So, first you have to import the login_manager

```py
from flask_login import login_manager
```

Then configure the application as indicated by the [flask_login documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuring-your-application)

```py
login_manager = LoginManager()

login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id): 
    # Change this to retrieve the user from the db
    return User.get(user_id)
```

I hope I've helped you

Comment: Hi, yeah thanks, i fixed the problem ^^, it was indeed the configuration.

Comment: Glad to helped you. If you believe this was the best solution to your problem, you might accept the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)